# Display a video at boot

Tags: cron

we want to show a video in the entrance hall with the activities of our company.

Now in crontab with`crontab -e` i have this line to open the movie file that we want to show.

```
@reboot vlc ~/Desktop/movie.mp4 -f --loop
```

But i don't see the movie after boot. Crontab executes the shutdown command every day at 18:00 pm

Comment: Does `~` refer to the home folder of root or the home folder of pi?

Answer (score 2):

Could use the command line version of VLC and output to the frame buffer so you don't have to boot into X11.

```
@reboot cvlc --no-osd --no-repeat -fLZ /home/pi/default.xspf vlc://quit
```

The upside of doing that is that omxplayer has been deprecated and VLC supports more file types.

Would probably use a small script so you can refresh the playlist as previously suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Likely what's happening is `vlc` is trying to start before Xorg does. For autostarting applications that require X to already be running, add your vlc command line to `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`.

Alternatively, use a video player that does not require a X session, such as `omxplayer`.

Answer (score 0):

my company's current solution for a kiosk is a root crontab

```
@reboot bash /home/pi/pi-kiosk/autostart.sh
```

inside /home/pi/pi-kiosk/autostart.sh :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while true
do
    omxplayer -o hdmi /home/pi/pi-kiosk/kiosk/* 2>> /home/pi/pi-kiosk/error.log 1> /dev/null
done
```

the pi-kiosk folder is setup as a samba share that we can just drag and drop video files to. I wrote the script this way to allow the video file to be hotswapped live because using a --loop parameter only works if the file never changes

the only downside i've seen to this is that there is no way to vnc in and visually verify that the video is playing, but you get much better framerates than if you WERE running VNC